# Row overflows while using container-fluid and panel using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a panel with rows inside a container-fluid with the following code and my rows overflows the container...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="row">
  <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>      
  <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...   </p>      
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>      
  <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>      
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdRpx/280/

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Your code and JSfiddle code is different. Did I fork it right? https://jsfiddle.net/jxzu889u/

Comment: It was my bad..I updated it

Answer (score 2):

Added Panel Body and includes the use of grids which are designed to work with rows. When you define a row you're meant to define a grid element. Or that's at least what the documentation seems to suggest.

You could use a second container rather than panel body and you'll notice panel body pushing the top and bottom of the page down so perhaps avoid h1 tags and find another tag inside bootstrap to enlarge font? What about a panel header?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>
                        <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>
                        <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

bootstrap.min.css contains the following:

```
.row {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;}
```

Overwriting the row class fixes this, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rdRpx/279/) fiddle

Comment: You should never overwrite the default bootstrap classes and the OP has updated the question with new fiddle.

Comment: why, if you need to adapt a style (I've not worked with bootstrap)? anyways, it's the reason it happens

Comment: What if the OP wants to use the row class for another container? You will still need to retain the margin properties right? :) Create a custom class and use priority selector.

Comment: this was just a high level answer to demonstrate that the row class was the cause; don't see why this should be downvoted; obviously you could do something like ".someclass .row" to overwrite only a specific context; alternatively, the container css could be adapted to adapt to the row

Comment: Your reasoning for the overflow is correct. I did not down vote, but the down vote reason seems that you have answered to different code and improper usage of overwriting. Maybe the markup can be also changed to create a solution. Please update your answer.